# Fancybox in the size of the div

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I want to know how to resize the fancybox in order to give it the same hight and width of the `div` that will be showed in the fancybox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For version 1.3

```
 $.fancybox.resize();
```

For version 2.0 or heigher Fancybox

```
 $.fancybox.update()
```

it resize the active fancybox based on the size of the content inside it.

Comment: i want to do it in the css and the script my fancybox don't work only when i make it in the class and the href als the result